# Show that $Y=aX+b$ is an random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be an random variable on a given probability space and let $a,b∈\mathbb R$.

Show that $Y=aX+b$ is an random variable.

If $X$ has a distribution function $F$, what is the distribution function of $Y$?

---

If $X$ is Celsius $Y=aX+b$ can be Fahrenheit and it's still a random variable but how can I show this?

Comment: Your questions are very basic. Don't you have a book/script at your disposal that handles the concept of 'random variable'? Your questions indicate that you have. Have a good look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P\right)$ be a probability space.

Then a random variable on it is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
such that $X^{-1}\left(B\right)=\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\in B\right\} \in\mathcal{A}$
for each Borelset $B$.

Denoting the collection of Borelsets on $\mathbb{R}$
by $\mathcal{B}$ we state that $\mathcal{B}$ is by definition the
smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open sets.

If you want
to prove that some function $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a
random variable then it is not necessary to check $Y^{-1}\left(B\right)\in\mathcal{A}$
for each Borelset $B$. If $\mathcal{V}\subset\wp\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
and $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains
$\mathcal{V}$ (in notation $\mathcal{B}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{V}\right)$)
then it is enough to check $Y^{-1}\left(B\right)\in\mathcal{A}$ for
sets $B\in\mathcal{V}$.

This **needs a proof** on its own, and is convenient, because there are collections
$\mathcal{V}$ that suffice $\mathcal{B}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{V}\right)$
and are easy to handle. For example the collection $\left\{ \left(-\infty,c\right]\mid c\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $.
Then proving that $Y=aX+b$ is a random variable is nothing more than
proving that $\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid aX\left(\omega\right)+b\leq c\right\} \in\mathcal{A}$
on base of the fact that $\left\{ \omega\in\Omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\in B\right\} \in\mathcal{A}$
is true for every Borelset $B$.

Give it a try.

A proof of what I stated can probably be found in your book/script.

Comment: Thak you. I am new to probability.

Answer (score 1):

To help you prove that $Y$ is a random variable, we need to know what kind of definition of random variables you are familiar with.

Regarding the distribution function: $F(t) = P(X \leq t)$. Let $F_Y$ be the distribution function of $Y$. Then
$$F_Y(t) = P(Y \leq t) = P(aX + b \leq t) = P\left(X \leq \frac{t-b}{a}\right) = F\left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)$$
if $a > 0$.

Comment: This answer is far beyond the level of the question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Sorry, I edited the answer to better fit the question.

Comment: You should assume here that $a>0$